# 1 byte difference in file size by counting and File.length()

Tags: java, file

I am comparing `File.length()` with counting bytes and I always get 1 byte more with `File.length()`.

Here is the snippet i am using to compare:

```
File testFile = new File("testdir", "testfile.txt");
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(testFile );

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int len = in.read(buffer);

int byteCount = len;
while (len != -1) {
    len = in.read(buffer);
    byteCount += len;
}
System.out.println("count: " + byteCount + ", file.length(): " + 
     testFile.length() + ", is_equal: "+(byteCount == testFile.length()));
```

and the output is `count: 15853294, file.length(): 15853295, is_equal: false`

Where does 1 byte come from? is it EOF?

Comment: Instead of `while (len != -1) {` I usually write `while ((len = inp.read(buffer)) != -1) {`, which exits the loop as soon as the read returns -1, instead of much later like yours does.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The last `read` operation returns -1 and you are adding this to `byteCount`.